# Searching Firebase JSON with Apache Drill

Tags: json, firebase, apache-drill

I've exported a portion of my data from https://domain.firebaseio.com/users/

```js
{
  "3": {
    "company": "",
    "d_year": "",
    "email": "mario.giambanco@domain.com",
    "facebook": "",
    "fullname": "Mario Test",
    "google": "",
    "igoto": "",
    "image": "",
    "notifications": {
      "-Jx6fpaJHvKPHc8CylPd": {
        "from": "System",
        "image": "/img/system_icon.jpg",
        "msg": "System:",
        "param": "3",
        "posteddate": 1440016723546,
        "type": "system"
      }
    },
    "school": "",
    "school_year": "",
    "tags": {
      "-JxWuEPs183UEwsI-XNb": {
        "title": "Anesthesia"
      },
      "-JxWuZ-ePcx0XqYRmzc6": {
        "title": "Bridges"
      }
    },
    "twitter": ""
  },
  "4": {
    "company": "",
    "d_year": "",
    "email": "mariogiambanco@domain.com",
    "fullname": "mario test",
    "igoto": "",
    "image": "img/a0.jpg",
    "notifications": {
      "-JxAQpWGzY-gOzej7Xis": {
        "from": "System",
        "image": "/img/system_icon.jpg",
        "msg": "System:",
        "param": "4",
        "posteddate": 1440079641420,
        "type": "system"
      }
    },
    "school": "",
    "school_year": ""
  }
}
```

Executing:
SELECT * FROM dfs.`/Users/me/Desktop/users.json`

works (or, at least I get a result)
[image]

But how do I map the columns to be values in the row. Looking at this coming from the relational database world, the column headings in the screen capture are unique ID's (3, 4) - those should be apart of the row, not column headings. Same would be true for the uniquely generated key that gets produced when using push({})

The goal is of course to do a Select Where (select * from data where fullname="Mario Test") for example

Is there some sort of pre-processing I should be doing to the JSON before searching it with Drill?

Comment: Are the indexed entries "3" and "4" supposed to be rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be another way to do this, but I'd say yes, you might want to transform the data slightly in order to query it with Drill.

This looks like a situation where you want to use KVGEN. KVGEN would give you the kind of columns that Chris Matta is describing, but KVGEN operates on a column, and in this case there isn't really a column to use:

```
0: jdbc:drill:zk=local> select t.* from dfs.`/Users/vince/data/stackoverflow/users.json` t;
+---+---+
| 3 | 4 |
+---+---+
| {"company":"","d_year":"","email":"mario.giambanco@domain.com","facebook":"","fullname":"Mario Test","google":"","igoto":"","image":"","notifications":{"-Jx6fpaJHvKPHc8CylPd":{"from":"System","image":"/img/system_icon.jpg","msg":"System:","param":"3","posteddate":1440016723546,"type":"system"}},"school":"","school_year":"","tags":{"-JxWuEPs183UEwsI-XNb":{"title":"Anesthesia"},"-JxWuZ-ePcx0XqYRmzc6":{"title":"Bridges"}},"twitter":""} | {"company":"","d_year":"","email":"mariogiambanco@domain.com","fullname":"mario test","igoto":"","image":"img/a0.jpg","notifications":{"-JxAQpWGzY-gOzej7Xis":{"from":"System","image":"/img/system_icon.jpg","msg":"System:","param":"4","posteddate":1440079641420,"type":"system"}},"school":"","school_year":""} |
+---+---+
1 row selected (0.133 seconds)
```

Since those columns are dynamic AND at the "top level" of the JSON object, you can't use KVGEN here. But if you transform the data just a little bit, you can use KVGEN. I used this invocation of the most excellent tool jq to massage the data into a format KVGEN can use:

```
$ jq '.| { "user": . }' < users.json > users_kv.json
```

This will take the input, and just wrap the JSON object in another map, which will give us the "static" column we need to do the following:

```
0: jdbc:drill:zk=local> select kvgen(t.`user`) from dfs.`/Users/vince/data/stackoverflow/users_kv.json` t;
+--------+
| EXPR$0 |
+--------+
| [{"key":"3","value":{"company":"","d_year":"","email":"mario.giambanco@domain.com","facebook":"","fullname":"Mario Test","google":"","igoto":"","image":"","notifications":{"-Jx6fpaJHvKPHc8CylPd":{"from":"System","image":"/img/system_icon.jpg","msg":"System:","param":"3","posteddate":1440016723546,"type":"system"},"-JxAQpWGzY-gOzej7Xis":{}},"school":"","school_year":"","tags":{"-JxWuEPs183UEwsI-XNb":{"title":"Anesthesia"},"-JxWuZ-ePcx0XqYRmzc6":{"title":"Bridges"}},"twitter":""}},{"key":"4","value":{"company":"","d_year":"","email":"mariogiambanco@domain.com","fullname":"mario test","igoto":"","image":"img/a0.jpg","notifications":{"-Jx6fpaJHvKPHc8CylPd":{},"-JxAQpWGzY-gOzej7Xis":{"from":"System","image":"/img/system_icon.jpg","msg":"System:","param":"4","posteddate":1440079641420,"type":"system"}},"school":"","school_year":"","tags":{"-JxWuEPs183UEwsI-XNb":{},"-JxWuZ-ePcx0XqYRmzc6":{}}}}] |
+--------+
1 row selected (1.774 seconds)
```

Still not really queryable in the way you want since I've got a list inside the column. So use FLATTEN:

```
0: jdbc:drill:zk=local> select flatten(kvgen(t.`user`)) as `user` from dfs.`/Users/vince/data/stackoverflow/users_kv.json` t;
+------+
| user |
+------+
| {"key":"3","value":{"company":"","d_year":"","email":"mario.giambanco@domain.com","facebook":"","fullname":"Mario Test","google":"","igoto":"","image":"","notifications":{"-Jx6fpaJHvKPHc8CylPd":{"from":"System","image":"/img/system_icon.jpg","msg":"System:","param":"3","posteddate":1440016723546,"type":"system"},"-JxAQpWGzY-gOzej7Xis":{}},"school":"","school_year":"","tags":{"-JxWuEPs183UEwsI-XNb":{"title":"Anesthesia"},"-JxWuZ-ePcx0XqYRmzc6":{"title":"Bridges"}},"twitter":""}} |
| {"key":"4","value":{"company":"","d_year":"","email":"mariogiambanco@domain.com","fullname":"mario test","igoto":"","image":"img/a0.jpg","notifications":{"-Jx6fpaJHvKPHc8CylPd":{},"-JxAQpWGzY-gOzej7Xis":{"from":"System","image":"/img/system_icon.jpg","msg":"System:","param":"4","posteddate":1440079641420,"type":"system"}},"school":"","school_year":"","tags":{"-JxWuEPs183UEwsI-XNb":{},"-JxWuZ-ePcx0XqYRmzc6":{}}}} |
+------+
2 rows selected (0.257 seconds)
```

Two rows - much better. Now you're ready to do what you wanted all along (note the subquery and also the backticks around reserved words user and value:

```
    0: jdbc:drill:zk=local> select u.`user`.`key` as userid, u.`user`.`value`.fullname as fullname, u.`user`.`value`.email as email from (select flatten(kvgen(t.`user`)) as `user` from dfs.`/Users/vince/data/stackoverflow/users_kv.json` t) u where u.`user`.`value`.fullname = 'Mario Test';
+---------+-------------+-----------------------------+
| userid  |  fullname   |            email            |
+---------+-------------+-----------------------------+
| 3       | Mario Test  | mario.giambanco@domain.com  |
+---------+-------------+-----------------------------+
1 row selected (0.22 seconds)
```

Comment: Awesome, this is a great way to go about solving this.

Answer (score 1):

A key shouldn't really hold a value, if in fact the keys "3" and "4" are ids. A better way to format this JSON for Drill would be to use actual keys for those values (also notice you can have multiple records per file, Drill can parse them):

```
{ "id": 3,
  "data": {
       ...
  }
}
{ "id": 4,
   "data": {
        ...
   }
}
```

That way you can do queries like this:

```
> select t.`id`, t.`data`.`fullname` as `fullname` from `firebase.json` t;
+-----+-------------+
| id  |  fullname   |
+-----+-------------+
| 3   | Mario Test  |
| 4   | mario test  |
+-----+-------------+
2 rows selected (0.269 seconds)
```